# VS Code replace C# variable declaration with TypeScript variable declaration using regex

Tags: c#, regex, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a task to convert an entire C# project to TypeScript.

Currently I have variables declared as `string abc` or `string xyz`.

How can I convert/replace all such occurrence to `abc: string` or `xyz: string`
using the regex feature of VS Code?

Comment: Have you seen that there exist plugins for visual studio to convert c# to typescript? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adrianwilczynski.csharp-to-typescript

Comment: oh that was awesome. why I didn't think of this first. :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Find: `string ([\p{L}\d_-]*)` (This will search for letters, numbers, "_" and "-", which are the valid variables identifiers)

Replace `$1: string`